# Insert JSON into Postgres 9.5

Tags: python, sql, postgresql

In **Python 3.6** I have a variable '**data2**' which contains a **JSON** that looks like this:

```
{
    'id': 4573457, 'account_id': 456, 'address': '15 Millers Rd, WA', 
    'category_id': 4565, 'description': None, 'is_anonymous': False, 
    'iso_created_at': '2017-11-21T14:08:54+11:00', 
    'location': {
        'latitude': -56.564848493, 'longitude': 345.5948493}, 
    'report_state_id': 45655, 'report_state_name': 'ALL PICKED', 
    'title': 'South', 'user_id': 44555, 'user_short_name': 'Todd G.', 
    'users_alerted_count': 0, 'users_opened_count': 6, 'shape_id': 56
}
```

I want to write an insert statement to insert this data into a table I have already created in **Postgres 9.5**, the table has 3 columns - *channel, report_id and report_data* -

I want to insert the 'account_id' from the JSON into the channel column, the 'id' into the report_id column and the rest of the JSON all into the report_data column.

Can someone please tell me how I can do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's the basic way to extract the JSON values in Postgres:

```
  data2->'account_id' AS channel
```

So, your execute SQL should be something like this:

```
cursor.execute("
    INSERT INTO MyTable (channel, report_id, report_data)
    SELECT 
      src.MyJSON->'account_id',
      src.MyJSON->'id',
      src.MyJSON
    FROM (
      SELECT %s AS MyJSON
    ) src
  ",
  (data2,)
)
```

If you want to remove the account_id/id keys before inserting the rest of the JSON into the report_data field, then you can create a second "data2" variable (i.e. "data2_final" with the removed keys and also pass that as a parameter to your SQL.  Let me know how it works for you.

**Updated**

```
CREATE TABLE Mytable (
  channel INTEGER, 
  report_id INTEGER, 
  report_data JSONB
);

cursor.execute("
    INSERT INTO MyTable (channel, report_id, report_data)
    SELECT 
      CAST(src.MyJSON->>'account_id' AS INTEGER),
      CAST(src.MyJSON->>'id' AS INTEGER),
      src.MyJSON
    FROM (
      SELECT CAST(%s AS JSONB) AS MyJSON
    ) src
  ",
  (data2,)
)
```

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!17/fb3af/1

I updated the extract to return the JSON values as text and then cast them as INTEGER.

**Updated Update**
I formatted your code below as I understood it with the changes I made noted below:

```
def calldb( db, sql_cmd): 
    try: 
        cur = db.cursor() 
        cur.execute(sql_cmd, (data2,)) 
        return 
    except Exception as e: 
        print ('Error ', e ) 
        raise 

sql_cmd=" INSERT INTO MyTable (channel, report_id, report_data) SELECT CAST(src.MyJSON->>'account_id' AS INTEGER), CAST(src.MyJSON->>'id' AS INTEGER), src.MyJSON FROM ( SELECT CAST(%s AS JSONB) AS MyJSON ) src" 
calldb(conn, sql_cmd) 
conn.commit()
```

**Changes**:

- removed the extra double-quotes at start and end of sql_cmd
- added a double-quote after "src" in the query
- moved the (data2,) tuple to the cur.execute() call

The way the execute() function works, is you pass it the SQL string you want to execute (i.e. sql_cmd) as the first parameter.  The %s thingies in the string are placeholders for the parameterized values.  As a second argument, you pass an array/tuple containing the parameter values (i.e. (data2,)).

Fingers crossed :)

**Updated Updated Update**
Here is the working code (slightly modified version from what you provided):

```
import psycopg2
import json

def calldb(db, sql_cmd, sql_params): 
    try: 
        cur = db.cursor()
        cur.execute(sql_cmd, sql_params)
        return
    except Exception as e: 
        print ('Error ', e ) 
        raise 

params = {
  "host":"DB_HOSTNAME",
  "database":"DB_NAME",
  "user":"USERNAME",
  "password":"PASSWORD"
}

conn = psycopg2.connect(**params)

# Prepare SQL
sql_cmd = "INSERT INTO MyTable (channel, report_id, report_data) SELECT CAST(src.MyJSON->>'account_id' AS INTEGER), CAST(src.MyJSON->>'id' AS INTEGER), src.MyJSON FROM ( SELECT CAST(%s AS JSONB) AS MyJSON ) src" 

# Convert dictionary to native JSON data type
data2 = {"id": 4573457, "account_id": 456, "address": "15 Millers Rd, WA"}
data2_json = json.dumps(data2)

sql_params = (data2_json,)

# Execute SQL
calldb(conn, sql_cmd, sql_params) 
conn.commit()
```

**Changes**

- added sql_params variable to calldb() to pass along sql parameters
- added connection params line to connect to DB (not sure how you were
  doing it in yours)
- converted data2 dictionary data type to JSON data type (that's related to why you were getting the previous "can't adapt dict" error)
- Suggestion: Not sure if you do this or not, but you should also close your DB cursor and connection when you're done with them

You can clean it up and modify as needed.  Give it a try and let me know.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Have tried the SQL above and it gives me an error:

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Have tried the SQL above and it gives me an error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "smartoysters_06122017_V1.py", line 163, in <module>
    calldb(conn, sql_cmd)
  File "smartoysters_06122017_V1.py", line 27, in calldb
    cur.execute(sql_cmd)
psycopg2.ProgrammingError: unterminated quoted string at or near "'
  ,(%s,)
)"
LINE 6:   )'
           ^

Comment: My SQL looks like this : """INSERT INTO MyTable (channel, report_id, report_data)
  VALUES(
        data2->'account_id',
        data2->'id',
        data2
  )'
  ,(%s,)
)"""

Comment: There were a couple issues with the original query.  I updated it above.  Give it a try.  I haven't tested it, so there may be some syntax errors.

Comment: Thanks for your help so far. Have tried the updated SQL and am getting the following error:  
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "smartoysters_06122017_V1.py", line 165, in <module>
    calldb(conn, sql_cmd)
  File "smartoysters_06122017_V1.py", line 27, in calldb
    cur.execute(sql_cmd)
psycopg2.ProgrammingError: syntax error at or near "%"
LINE 7:       SELECT %s AS MyJSON
                     ^

Comment: Hmm I'm still getting an error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "smartoysters_06122017_V1.py", line 167, in <module>
    calldb(conn, sql_cmd)
  File "smartoysters_06122017_V1.py", line 27, in calldb
    cur.execute(sql_cmd)
psycopg2.ProgrammingError: syntax error at or near "%"
LINE 7:       SELECT CAST(%s AS JSONB) AS MyJSON
                          ^

Comment: Can you please post all the relevant python code to reproduce the error?  The error message sounds more like a Python one, so I'm guessing the SQL never even hits the DB.

Comment: def calldb( db, sql_cmd):
    try:
        cur = db.cursor()  
       
        cur.execute(sql_cmd)
        return  

    except Exception as e:
        print ('Error ', e )
        raise
sql_cmd="""

    INSERT INTO MyTable (channel, report_id, report_data)
    SELECT 
      CAST(src.MyJSON->>'account_id' AS INTEGER),
      CAST(src.MyJSON->>'id' AS INTEGER),
      src.MyJSON
    FROM (
      SELECT CAST(%s AS JSONB) AS MyJSON
    ) src
  ,
  (data2,)
)"""
  
  
calldb(conn, sql_cmd)
    
    
    
conn.commit()

Comment: It looks like you're missing a double-quote after the "src" in the SQL.  See my Updated Updated note above.

Comment: Now im getting this error: Error  can't adapt type 'dict'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "smartoysters_06122017_V1.py", line 157, in <module>
    calldb(conn, sql_cmd)
  File "smartoysters_06122017_V1.py", line 27, in calldb
    cur.execute(sql_cmd, (data2,))
psycopg2.ProgrammingError: can't adapt type 'dict'

Comment: Sorry, time to sleep.  Keep playing around with it.

Comment: Thanks very much for your help so far! No I'm still struggling with getting this to work.

Comment: You got it my friend.  Check the updated updated update.  There is a working example that you can modify as needed.

Comment: Seems to work! Thank you, but how can i view the table in Postgres to check it has been populated?

Comment: Awesome.  Just logon using any SQL client and do a `SELECT * FROM MyTable`.  Assuming you're on windows and have access to the Postgres psql client, open a command prompt and connect like so: `psql -W <db_name> <user_name>.`  Then put in the password when prompted.  You may have to futz around to connect to the correct database/namespace that houses your table.  A couple links: 
 https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/tutorial-accessdb.html  https://www.a2hosting.com/kb/developer-corner/postgresql/connect-to-postgresql-from-the-command-line

Comment: Hi how can i insert something within a JSON array into Postgres 9.5?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to INSERT?  Take a look at the documentation for the basic functions: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-json.html . If you get stuck, please post some more details.

Comment: [{'eReal': [1060, -740, -324, 542130, 377694, -164889], 'eRealNegative': [0, 740, 324, 0, 0, 164889], 'eRealPositive': [1060, 0, 0, 542130, 377694, 0], 'eReactive': [-244, -791, 1041, -124663, 399793, 526182], 'eReactiveNegative': [244, 791, 0, 124663, 0, 0], 'eReactivePositive': [0, 0, 1041, 0, 399793, 526182], 'vRMSMin': [249.9, 248.1, 248.3, 249.9, 248.2, 248.3], 'vRMSMax': [250.7, 249.4, 249.7, 250.8, 249.4, 249.7], 'iRMSMin': [0.026, 0.026, 0.026, 7.375, 7.34, 7.359], 'iRMSMax': [0.028, 0.029, 0.029, 7.45, 7.413, 7.435], 'timestamp': 1513221900, 'duration': 300}] The array after eReal

Comment: into a column called eReal

Comment: Use the "->" and "-->" operators to extract individual values: `src.MyJSON->'eReal'` (get value as JSON object) OR `src.MyJSON->>'eReal'` (get value as text).  If you want to use the extracted value as a native ARRAY type, then just cast it as an array.

Answer (score 1):

The answer above is somewhat complicated.

From the psycopg2 [office document](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/extras.html), there is class type call `psycopg2.extras.Json` which is an ISQLQuote wrapper to adapt a Python object to json data type.

```
import psycopg2
import logging
from psycopg2.extras import Json

conn = psycopg2.connect(dbname="  ", 
                        user="  ",
                        password="  ", 
                        host="127.0.0.1", 
                        port="5432")
data2 = {
    'id': 4573457, 'account_id': 456, 'address': '15 Millers Rd, WA', 
    'category_id': 4565, 'description': None, 'is_anonymous': False, 
    'iso_created_at': '2017-11-21T14:08:54+11:00', 
    'location': {
        'latitude': -56.564848493, 'longitude': 345.5948493}, 
    'report_state_id': 45655, 'report_state_name': 'ALL PICKED', 
    'title': 'South', 'user_id': 44555, 'user_short_name': 'Todd G.', 
    'users_alerted_count': 0, 'users_opened_count': 6, 'shape_id': 56
}

item = {
    'channel': data2['account_id'],
    'report_id': data2['id'],
    'report_data': Json(dict([(k, v) for k, v in data2.items() if k not in ['account_id', 'id']]))
}



def sql_insert(tableName, data_dict):
    '''
        INSERT INTO onetable (channel,  report_id,  report_data)
        VALUES (%(channel)s, %(report_id)s, %(report_data)s );
    '''
    sql = '''
        INSERT INTO %s (%s)
        VALUES (%%(%s)s );
        '''   % (tableName, ',  '.join(data_dict),  ')s, %('.join(data_dict))
    return sql

tableName = 'onetable'
sql = sql_insert(tableName, item)
try:
    with conn.cursor() as cur:
        cur.execute(sql, item)
    conn.commit()
except Exception as e:
    logging.debug(e)
    conn.rollback()
finally:
    conn.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can insert using jsonb data type.
Pls refer to link below .
https://www.compose.com/articles/faster-operations-with-the-jsonb-data-type-in-postgresql/